# Regular expression for a string that does not start and ends with a sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
 filter('highlight', function() {
 return function(data, search) {
     if (data) {
        data = data.toString();
        if (search) {
             for(var i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
                data = data.replace( new RegExp( "(" + preg_quote( search[i] ) + ")" , 'gi' ), "<span class='search-highlight'>$1</span>" );
             }
        }
     }
     return data;
 };}).
```

i need to highlight the **data** if it contains any element of **search**. if data is "foo@bar.com" and search contains "foo", the function will return `<span ..>foo</span>@bar.com`.

Problem is if the search array contains "foo","a" ,  the function returns `<sp<span ..>a</span>n ..>foo</span>@bar.com` which breaks the view of page.

Idea is I have to skip anything that already surrounded with `<span></span>` tag. How can I do this?

Comment: Rather than modifying the `data` string in place and successively adding marked up values, can you build the final string in another object and concatenate everything together at the end? That way you could avoid matching on the modifications you've substituted.

Comment: that's an useful thought! Can you help how can I do it...?

Comment: Why cook all food yourself? Go restaurants sometimes. 
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/search-highlight/

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan My food is healthier and better for my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic example of why you do not mix HTML and Regex.

You have a DOM, use it!

First, use the regex to find the position of the match. This can be done by calling `regex.exec(string)` and then getting `regex.lastIndex`. This tells you where the regex has searched up to. Call `textNode.splitText()` using that `lastIndex`, then again minus the length of the match. This will separate the matched text from the rest. You can then wrap this inside an element.

Repeat for all text nodes, and all searches.

I'll leave the exact code as an exercise for you, but this will be much, MUCH more reliable.

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestion! but will this process work if my **data**  is "foo@bar.com foo" and **search** terms are "foo","bar"? Please let me know the details :(

Comment: Can you give me the exact solution? @Niet

Comment: Because I'm bored: http://jsfiddle.net/hn2bpz0y/ Try and understand how it works ;)

Comment: search with the terms "**o**","**foo**" , it won't show expected result :( @Niet

Comment: i thought you didn't give up :( @Niet

Comment: It shows exactly the result I would expect, however if you want to try and avoid this problem, consider adding `terms.sort(function(a,b) {return b.length-a.length;});` right at the start of the function. This will make it process longer search terms first.